# If the result of an anonymous function is assigned to a variable, is that function called every time the variable is called?

Tags: javascript

So if have:

```
var num = (function(){
  return 1 + 1;
})();
```

Will that function be processed every time I use that variable? Or is it only processed the first time the browser reads over the script and the return result 'permanently' assigned to that variable?

Comment: FYI, you could return a function that returns `1 + 1` but you'd need to invoke it every time, like `num()`. Or if it's an object property, you can assign a "getter" function that will be invoked each time the property is accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make a test, consider the following script :

```
var timestamp = (function(){
 return Date.now();
})();

console.log('variable at time t : ' + timestamp);

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('variable at time t+1s : ' + timestamp);
}, 1000);
```

This returns the same timestamp, we can conclude that the timestamp variable is assigned the value of the self-calling function only once.

Comment: The result is entirely predictable, there is no need to treat the language as a black box. An answer should explain why the result occurs, not make presumptions based on behaviour. An identical result could be obtained if the function was run every time but the result was held in a closure so it always returns the same value.

Comment: I already knew the answer myself and I agree with your statement, I just wanted a way to make sure that OP understands, which is in my opinion the priority.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is not a lazy language. ("Imperative" is one way to describe the language; I'm not the one to give the most accurate term.) The expression on the right-hand side of the `=` assignment operator will be evaluated once, and the result will be stored in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){ return 1 + 1; })();
```

is a `self-executing anonymous function`. Which means it will be executed as it is defined once and its value returned. If you want the function to be assigned to a variable simply use

```
var func = function(){ }
```